# Regexp: Star overriding a greedy optional item

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have a puzzle for you regexp-gods out there. :)

I'm quite baffled, by this regular extension:

```
^.*DST=(?<DST>[^ ]*).*(?:TTL=(?<TTL>[^ ]*))?.*PROTO=(?<PROTO>[^ ]*).*$
```

([Debuggex-Setup for that](https://www.debuggex.com/r/NyJp8yl-tmfBdmlr))

I have this test string:

```
Oct 24 11:43:29 127.0.0.1 kernel: [22592645.391497] WATCH IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:a0:48:1c:55:50:70:08:00 SRC=10.10.1.1 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=267 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=16 ID=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=3490 DPT=3490 LEN=247
```

I'd like to match the DST, TTL and PROTO-values, while the TTL-value is optional and could be left out in another line.

However, the TTL-group doesn't match, if it's set to optional. As I understood the ?-token, it should be greedy, so when there IS a TTL-group, it should match that. What I'm seeing is, that the *-token is seemingly greedier than the ?-token. I tried making the *-token lazy, but that didn't work either.

Can somebody explain that to me?

Thanks.

Kind regards

Dennis

Comment: As a general remark relevant to the problem. Avoid `.*` as much as possible. Should it really match ANYTHING? No, it shouldn't match `TTL`, so _tell_ it not to match `TTL`. This is what you see the answerers do. `.*` or `.+` is **rarely** what you actually wanna match, and `.*?` making it non-greedy only does so much.

Comment: Yes, you are right, funkwurm. I am doing that already. This was a kind of example-wrapup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `.*` inside of your non-capturing group making it optional as well.

```
^.*DST=(?<DST>[^ ]*)(?:.*TTL=(?<TTL>[^ ]*))?.*PROTO=(?<PROTO>[^ ]*).*$
```

You can use `\S` instead of the negated character classes if you prefer which matches any non-whitespace character and I would avoid using `*` and use `+` instead following the first few with a non-greedy quantifier `+?`.

```
^.+?DST=(?<DST>\S+)(?:.+?TTL=(?<TTL>\S+))?.+?PROTO=(?<PROTO>\S+).+$
```

I recommend reading the article ["The Greedy Trap"](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) to understand the difference.

Comment: To add more detail, the OP's second `.*` shoots the regexp engine straight to the end of the string and then it starts to backtrack, matching an empty TTL group followed by the PROTO group first.

Comment: Thank you very much, hwnd! That's it! And I also understood it now. :D

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
^.*?DST=(?<DST>[^ ]*)(?:(?!TTL=).)*(?:TTL=(?<TTL>[^ ]*))?.*PROTO=(?<PROTO>[^ ]*).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qW8wQ6/10)

A reduced one,

```
^.*?DST=(?<DST>\S*)(?:(?!TTL=).)*(?:TTL=(?<TTL>\S*))?.*PROTO=(?<PROTO>\S*).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qW8wQ6/11)

`(?:(?!TTL=).)*` Matches any character but not of `TTL=` zero or more times.